# undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

When I create a new user and view the user's profile Im getting the following error I think because the user has not created a status yet:

```
undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass
```

It's coming from Status_form:

```
<%= form_for [@status], :url => user_status_path(current_user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, id:"status_box", maxlength:350, placeholder: "Say something." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Update", id:"status_btn", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>

  <span id="counter">Characters left: <%= 350 - @status.content.length %></span> #this is the source of the error

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#status_box').keyup(function () {
        var left = 350 - $(this).val().length;
        if (left < 0) {
            left = 0;
        }
        $('#counter').text('Characters left: ' + left);
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

User Controller:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @status = @user.status || @user.build_status
end
```

Comment: Its because you have default value `nil` for `content` in database. If you change it to empty string you will get `@status.content.length` as `0`. Try using `<%= 350 - @status.content.to_s.length %>`

Comment: Thanks. How do I change it exactly? I have a statuses table with a content attribute. Must I run a migration? and how would i set it up?

Comment: Ya u need to run migration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you have default value `nil` for `content` column. So you can't call `length` on `nil`. If you want to use `length` on `content` you need to set `default` value as `empty string("")` or you can use `to_s` first and then `length`

```
   <%= 350 - @status.content.to_s.length %>
```

or

```
   <%= 350 - (@status.content.try(:length) || 0) %>
```

Comment: I think that did the trick but im going to check again. Does the to_s set it to an empty string automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your controller:

```
  @status = @user.status || @user.build_status
```

and it looks like the error is coming from

```
@status.content.length
```

I would bet that the 'content' for @status is nil.

Comment: It is. I'm saying I havn't created a status yet thus I get an error from that line. What should i do?

Comment: You could either default content in the DB to be zero, or you do something like `@status.content.try(:length)||0`